# Is there a way to reprogram a 2.4 GHz wireless mouse USB dongle?

Tags: wireless-mouse

I bought a wireless mouse that came with a USB dongle, but the dongle broke because someone accidentally stepped on it.

I bought another one previously from the same company and same type of mouse, but the mouse broke because I dropped it by accident and its dongle is fine, but the mouse isn't working.

So I have two of the same mice, one is intact with a broken USB receiver dongle and another is broken with a good USB receiver dongle. Is there a way to reprogram the receiver to work with the non broken one?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, there is a 'pair' button on the mouse and/or on the dongle. If you press the button(s), the mouse and dongle are paired. (This is not the same as pairing under Bluetooth).

Other mice require turning it off and then on again using a switch on the mouse or taking the batteries out for a few seconds.

If that doesn't work, there might be a pairing utility that came with the mouse on its installation CD or you can download a pairing utility from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: There's no pair button. It's just a standard usb dongle and mouse has only navigational buttons (right & left click) I'm not talking about bluetooth by the way.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi I added a few more options.

Comment: yeah there was no installation CD, it's a nexxtech mouse that's plug and play: http://www.thesource.ca/estore/product.aspx?language=en-ca&catalog=online&category=Mice_Cordless&product=8015891 or a video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7piWxImFPw